# What's the proper way to inject Entity-based classes in Spring IoC

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Please bear with me:

We have a setup of *Hibernate* and *Spring IoC*, in which for each entity (`User`, `Customer`, `Account`, `Payment`, `Coupon`, etc) there's a bunch of "singleton" interfaces and implementation classes that support it.
For example: for`Customer`:

```
@Entity
public class Customer extends BaseEntity {
  ...
  public name();
}

/* base API */
public interface Service {
  public create();
  public list();
  public find();
  public update();
  public delete();
}

/* specific API */
public interface CustomerService extends Service {
  public findByName();
}

/* specific implementation */
public class CustomerServiceImpl extends BaseService implements CustomerService {
  ...
}
```

And this pattern goes on and on (`CustomerManager`, `CustomerDataProvider`, `CustomerRenderer`, etc.).

finally, in order work against an instance of a specific API (e.g. `CustomerService.findByName()`), a static global holder had evolved - which makes references like the following available:

```
public class ContextHolder {
  private static AbstractApplicationContext appContext;

  public static final CustomerService getCustomerService() {
      return appContext.getBean(CustomerService.class);
  }
  //... omitting methods for each entity class X supporting class 
}

@Configuration
public class ServicesConfiguration {
  @Bean(name = "customerService")
  @Lazy(false)
  public CustomerService CustomerService() {
      return new CustomerServiceImpl();
  }
  //... omitting methods for each entity class X supporting class 
}
```

### So, the question is:

**what would be the proper way to inject those supporting classes**, e.g. `CustomerService`, **given an entity instance**, for the following uses:

1. I have a specific entity (e.g. a `Customer`), and would like to get a service and call a specific API (e.g. `findByName()`)?
2. I have an entity (don't care which one in specific), and would like to call a general API (e.g. `find()`)

**All this, while avoiding global static references** (and thus, swap implementations in e.g. tests, and simplify the caller code).

So i can get a any supporting class if I have an entity instance

```
BaseEntity entity = ... // not injected
Iservice service = ...// should be injected
service.create(entity);
```

or, get all the supporting classes I need for a given entity type

```
/* specific implementation */
public class CustomerServiceImpl extends BaseService implements CustomerService {
  // inject specific supporting classes
  @Autowire CustomerManager manager;
  @Autowire CustomerDataProvider provider; 
  @Autowire CustomerRenderer renderer; 
  @Autowire CustomerHelper helper; 
  ...
}
```

and, change the configuration a bit in other scenarios

```
// how to configure Spring to inject this double?
Class CustomerManagerDouble extends CustomerManager {...}

@Autowired @Test public void testSpecificAPI(CustomerService service) {
  service.doSomethingSpecific();
  assert ((CustomerManagerDouble) service.getManager()).checkSomething();
}
```

Comment: Your use case descriptions are a little unclear, what does "given an entity instance" mean? Is its type known at compile-time? If so, is there any reason why you can't just directly inject `CustomerService` into classes that deal with `Customer`s? Can you show an example of the sort of code you expect to work?

Comment: please see my last edit. What happened over time is that the `ContextHolder` was filled with static references (that way we can "get" a `CustomerService` anywhere in the code), and in cases which the concrete type is known only in runtime (or when we're using the base API, like `Service.update()`) there are actually big if/else switches to determine which `Service` instance to call.

Comment: This sounds like you're using Spring very, very, very wrong - the point of Spring is to *not* inject a single class with everything, and then retrieve service instances from there. Just inject the services *as close as possible* to where they're used. If `Service.update()` does a bunch of branching, the method probably shoudln't exist at all.

Comment: @Inerdial I'm trying to shift the current setup towards the right way - that's why I've posted the Q... Anyway, I'll try to inject as close as I can, and see if a pattern will emerge. thanks.

Comment: The mindset you want to keep is to avoid injecting a class with everything, or with objects it won't use, or ones it can't use directly – without casting etc. So inject as close as you can, inject an object typed as specifically as possible, and if this isn't possible consider whether the object should be redesigned, or if it should be managed by Spring.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but I *think* you want to inject entity objects (created by Hibernate) with services, right?

If that's the case, use the @Configurable annotation as described in the Spring 3.1 documentation:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable

Note that you have to use AspectJ to weave the entity classes (load-time or compile-time) for this to work.

Comment: It's still unclear what it is you're hoping to achieve.

You can maintain autowiring by type if there is exactly one implementation in the application context, otherwise you have to use the @ Resource or @ Autowired with @ Qualifier("namedService") annotation.